# jQuery events don't occur after I change button class

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I am trying to change my buttons' classes when being clicked so as to perform different actions the next time they are clicked. (I do not want to use toggle)

After changing the class, the next time these buttons are clicked nothing occurs even though the class has been changed. Can anyone please help me out? I am just starting to pick up jQuery so I don't know a lot of advanced mechanisms.

```
 $(".showcontactbutton").click(function(){
    $("#contactform").show();
    //$(this).attr('class', 'hidecontactbutton');
    $(this).removeClass('showcontactbutton').addClass('hidecontactbutton');
    $(this).text("Hide Contact Form");
    //html("<button id='hidecontactbutton'>Hide Contact Form</button>");

});

$(".hidecontactbutton").click(function(){
    alert("Works:");
    $("#contactform").hide();
    //$(this).attr('id', 'showcontactbutton');
    $(this).removeClass('hidecontactbutton').addClass('showcontactbutton');
    $(this).text("Contact Us");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `<button>` doesn't have a `type` attribute then it defaults to `type='"submit"`. This isn't obvious if said `<button>` wasn't in a `<form>` but if it is in a `<form>` then every click would initiate default behavior of a submit event:

- Collect all values of all form controls that have a `[name]` attribute nested within the `<form>`.
- Send all values to the server indicated by the `action` attribute.
- ***Reset `<form>`***

So add `type="button"` to the `<button>`

```
<button id='hidecontactbutton' type="button">...</button>
```

As for toggling the state of `#contact`, you should target the #id of the button and then switch classes. Was it your intention to have the classes on the button instead of `#contact`? `$(this)` refers to whatever was clicked (in this context that should be the button).

```js
$('#hideShow').on('click', hideShow);

function hideShow(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('hide')) {
    $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show').text('Hide Contact Form');
    $('#contact').show();
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide').text('Contact Us');
    $('#contact').hide();
  }
};
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18ch;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#contact {
  display: none;
  width: fit-content;
}

[type=submit] {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<button id='hideShow' class='hide' type='button'>Contact Us</button>
<form>
  <fieldset id='contact'>
    <legend>Contact Us</legend>
    <label for='email'>Email: </label><br>
    <input type='email'><br>
    <label for='email'>Comment: </label><br>
    <textarea></textarea><br>
    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The button I have problems with is outside the form though.

Comment: Updated HTML and it works inside or outside of form.

Answer (score 3):

Events on element are binded on load, so when you change class on which is element binded the event is lost. Either bind event to class you don't change or bind event to document like.

```
$(document).on("click", ".showcontactbutton" , function() {
    ...
]);
```

For more info search for binding on dynamic elements.